# Restore DB using a bak file. The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing database

Tags: sql-server, database, restore

I am attempting to restore a DB for example versionB using a .bak file of version A.

It seems like that is not the right thing to do because I am getting an error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore of database 'B' failed.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'B' database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite a database with a backup taken from a different database you must specify the [WITH REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#REPLACEoption) option in the RESTORE command.

> REPLACE should be used rarely and only after careful consideration.
>   Restore normally prevents accidentally overwriting a database with a
>   different database. If the database specified in a RESTORE statement
>   already exists on the current server and the specified database family
>   GUID differs from the database family GUID recorded in the backup set,
>   the database is not restored. This is an important safeguard.